# Getting Data from GET request on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get data from a URL that gives JSON output to an Angular project.

When I follow `http://localhost:3000/booking` on the browser it gives following output

```
[{"_id":"5cf35bbebaa52f4ab2f27b81","firstname":"lahiru","lastname":"madushan","email":"lahiru@lahiru.com","contact":770095174,"comments":"Done","xl":2,"md":1,"sm":3,"store":null,"pickup":null,"store_id":"df4xrttfvy","__v":0},
 {"_id":"5cf3762e7410e55137b65c4e","firstname":"lahiru","lastname":"madushan","email":"lahiru@lahiru.com","contact":770095174,"comments":"Done","xl":2,"md":1,"sm":10,"store":null,"pickup":null,"store_id":"df4xrttfvy","__v":0}
]
```

But When I try to get this using angular service and store it in local storage. But When I check the LocalStorage data is not there.

This is the **service.ts** file

```js
  getBookings(): Observable<Booking[]>{
    return this.http.get<Booking[]>('http://localhost:3000/booking/');
  }
```

and **component.ts** file

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookingService.getBookings()
    .subscribe(data => this.bookings = data);

    localStorage.setItem('bookings', JSON.stringify(this.bookings));
  }
```

This does not give any errors in the console.

Please Tell me What have I done wrong hear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: **TL;DR**: do it *inside* the callback. That's the point of callbacks.

Comment: Show booking class..

Comment: set your localstorage inside your subscribe call....remember observables are async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your `ngOnInit()` like this [i.e move your `localStorage.setItem('bookings', JSON.stringify(this.bookings));` inside subscribe()] -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.bookingService.getBookings()
    .subscribe(data => {
          this.bookings = data;
          localStorage.setItem('bookings', JSON.stringify(this.bookings));
     });
  }
```

You are trying to access this.bookings before it is filled by subscribe callback.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any data in the subscribtion?
Try to do console.log(data) inside to check what comes from the backend.

Also please check if in app.module in providers array the service is imported.

Comment: When i do a console log it returns an empty array

Comment: Hmm what about trailing slash in the URL? Try to remove it

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer, if you want the data outside subcription block you have to wait for the data for example try the below code,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.bookingService.getBookings()
    .subscribe(data => {
          this.bookings = data;
     });
setTimeout(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('bookings', JSON.stringify(this.bookings));
},1000);
  }
```

but this is not the Async way we can use promise or async/await to achive Async way. let me know if you want we can discuss.